# Adding php Session data inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, session

This is my function on inserting a given piece of text into a text field, If the user leaves it blank.
I'm unsure of how to replace: `"userid 46"`   with: `"userid <?= $_SESSION["user"]["id"]  ?>"`
Here is my function script.

```
function InsertDefaultValues()
{
    // Leave this line as is. Customization follows.
    var FieldsAndDefault = new Array();
    // Customization:
    // For each field that will have custom information is 
    //   submitted blank, use this format:
    //     FieldsAndDefault.push("FieldIDvalue Default value");

    FieldsAndDefault.push("userid 46");

    // End of customization.
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    for( var i=0; i<FieldsAndDefault.length; i++ )
    {
        FieldsAndDefault[i] = FieldsAndDefault[i].replace(/^\s*/,"");
        var pieces = FieldsAndDefault[i].split(" ");
        var field = pieces.shift();
        var f = document.getElementById(field);
        if( f.value.length < 1 ) { f.value = pieces.join(" "); }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you nearly had it.

```
FieldsAndDefault.push("userid <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id']; ?>");
```

Comment: `<?=` is a shortcut for `<?php echo` in any case, though not always available if short_tags was off in <5.4.0

Comment: Yes I know this. I was trying to keep the answer as clear and as simple as possible so someone without a more advanced understanding could see the basic structure.